# Ansible: Defined object getting 'dict object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible

I'm creating a kickstart file with Ansible. The playbook fails when I try to add --grow to the lv I'm creating.

This works in my j2.cfg file when I define the pv:

```
{% for part in item.partitions|default([]) %}
part {{ part.name }} --size {{ part.size_mib }}{{ ' --asprimary' if part.primary else '' }}{{ ' --grow' if part.grow else '' }}{% if part.fstype is defined %} --fstype={{ part.fstype }}{% endif %} --ondrive={{ part.drive }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then fails when I define the lv:

```
{% for vol in item.logvols|default([]) %}
logvol {{ vol.mount }} --name={% if vol.mount != '/' %}lv_{{ vol.mount | regex_replace('^/', '') | replace('-','__') | replace(' ','___') | replace('/','_') }}{% else %}lv_root{% endif %} --vgname=vg_{{ item.hostname | replace('-','_') }}_{{ vol.volgroup }} --fstype={{ vol.fstype | default('xfs') }} --size={{ vol.size_mib }}{{ ' --grow' if vol.grow else '' }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I run the ansible playbook with verbose it show that the object is defined.

```
"logvols": [
                    {
                        "fstype": "xfs", 
                        "grow": true, 
                        "mount": "/", 
                        "size_mib": 1, 
                        "volgroup": "main"
```

But errors with:

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'grow'"
```

If I take out the `{{ ' --grow' if vol.grow else '' }}` from logvols it works and creates the file with --grow in the partition section.

For the life of me I can't determine why it works once but not again.

Here are how the variables are defined.

```
partitions:
  - { name: /boot, fstype: ext2, primary: true, grow: false, size_mib: "{{ 2*1024 | int }}", drive: sda }
  - { name: pv.01, drive: sda, fstype: lvmpv, primary: true, size_mib: 1, grow: true }

volgroups:
  - { name: main, device: pv.01 }

logvols:
  - { mount: swap, fstype: swap, volgroup: main, size_mib: "{{ 4*1024 | int }}" }
  - { mount: /, volgroup: main, size_mib: 1, grow: true, fstype: xfs }
```

Comment: Please update this question to include a *runnable* playbook that reproduces the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: => `{{ ' --grow' if vol.grow | d(false) | bool else '' }}`

Comment: And since this is a list, you most likely have another item that the one you provided missing the `grow` attribute.

Comment: @Zeitounator - Thank you! Adding the default worked wonders. I'm curious as to why the other loop didn't require the same? Either way, if you want to post your answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: @Jeight: all elements in `partitions` have the `grow` key. The first element in `logvols` does not have the `grow` key. You might have the same problem tomorrow on the first list and  you should probably add the default there too. Thanks for proposing to add my answer. But this is actually a "could not reproduce or caused by a typo" type of question so I voted to close it accordingly.